# Conditional Spark map() function based on input columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What I'm trying to achieve here is sending to Spark SQL `map` function conditionally generated columns depending on if they have `null`, `0` or any other value I may want.

Take for example this initial DF.

```
val initialDF = Seq(
  ("a", "b", 1), 
  ("a", "b", null), 
  ("a", null, 0)
).toDF("field1", "field2", "field3")
```

From that initial DataFrame I want to generate yet another column which will be a map, like this.

```scala
initialDF.withColumn("thisMap", MY_FUNCTION)
```

My current approach to this is basically take a `Seq[String]` in a method a `flatMap` the key-value pairs that the Spark SQL method receives, like this.

```scala
def toMap(columns: String*): Column = {
  map(
    columns.flatMap(column => List(lit(column), col(column))): _*
  )
}
```

But then, filtering becomes a Scala thing and is quite a mess.

What I would like to obtain after the processing would be, for each of those rows, the next DataFrame.

```
val initialDF = Seq(
  ("a", "b", 1, Map("field1" -> "a", "field2" -> "b", "field3" -> 1)),
  ("a", "b", null, Map("field1" -> "a", "field2" -> "b")),
  ("a", null, 0, Map("field1" -> "a"))
)
  .toDF("field1", "field2", "field3", "thisMap")
```

I was wondering if this can be achieved using the `Column` API which is way more intuitive with `.isNull` or `.equalTo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small improvement on Lamanus' answer above which only loops over `df.columns` once:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Record(field1: String, field2: String, field3: java.lang.Integer)

val df = Seq(
  Record("a", "b", 1),
  Record("a", "b", null),
  Record("a", null, 0)
).toDS

df.show

// +------+------+------+
// |field1|field2|field3|
// +------+------+------+
// |     a|     b|     1|
// |     a|     b|  null|
// |     a|  null|     0|
// +------+------+------+

df.withColumn("thisMap", map_concat(
    df.columns.map { colName => 
        when(col(colName).isNull or col(colName) === 0, map())
        .otherwise(map(lit(colName), col(colName)))
    }: _*
)).show(false)

// +------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
// |field1|field2|field3|thisMap                                |
// +------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
// |a     |b     |1     |[field1 -> a, field2 -> b, field3 -> 1]|
// |a     |b     |null  |[field1 -> a, field2 -> b]             |
// |a     |null  |0     |[field1 -> a]                          |
// +------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

I found a way to achieve the expected result but it is a bit dirty.

```
val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df) { (df, n) => df.withColumn(n + "_map", map(lit(n), col(n))) }
val col_cond = df.columns.map(n => when(not(col(n + "_map").getItem(n).isNull || col(n + "_map").getItem(n) === lit("0")), col(n + "_map")).otherwise(map()))
df2.withColumn("map", map_concat(col_cond: _*))
  .show(false)
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

Here is my try with the function `map_from_arrays` that is possible to use in spark 2.4+.

```
df.withColumn("array", array(df.columns.map(col): _*))
  .withColumn("map", map_from_arrays(lit(df.columns), $"array")).show(false)
```

Then, the result is:

```
+------+------+------+---------+---------------------------------------+
|field1|field2|field3|array    |map                                    |
+------+------+------+---------+---------------------------------------+
|a     |b     |1     |[a, b, 1]|[field1 -> a, field2 -> b, field3 -> 1]|
|a     |b     |null  |[a, b,]  |[field1 -> a, field2 -> b, field3 ->]  |
|a     |null  |0     |[a,, 0]  |[field1 -> a, field2 ->, field3 -> 0]  |
+------+------+------+---------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: hm... I noticed that I have null value maps. I will dig it more.